# wxPython Toolbook/Toolbar, blank space between toolbar and frame

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython, toolbar, wxnotebook

[image: Line between toolbar and frame]

The screenshot is a snip of the left side of my main frame.  This frame has a toolbook at the top.  I've set the background color of both the toolbar in the toolbook and the frame to 0,0,0 but, as you can see, there is a small blank line between the two.  How do I get that line gone or how do I make it black, as well?

As a quick side question -- is there a way to change the color of the "selected" halo on the toolbar to something a bit more contrasted for black?  You can see the very faint blue halo around that first icon, I'd like that to be a much lighter blue, if possible.

EDIT: Code added --

```
il = wx.ImageList(128, 128)
        for tab in self.package.vars["tabs"]:
            il.Add(wx.Image(self.package.vars["iconPath"].format(tab), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        self.AssignImageList(il)
        imageIdGenerator = self.getNextImageID(il.GetImageCount())

        pages = [(wx.Panel(parent = self.parent, id = wx.ID_ANY), name.capitalize()) for name in self.package.vars["tabs"]]
        imID = 0
        toolbar = self.GetToolBar()
        toolbar.SetBackgroundColour(self.package.vars["bgColor"])
        toolbar.AddStretchableSpace()
        for page, label in pages:
            self.AddPage(page, label, imageId=imageIdGenerator.next())
            page.SetBackgroundColour(c.COLORS["green"])
            imID += 1
        toolbar.AddStretchableSpace()
```

Comment: Maybe you might want to add some code?

Comment: I added the code that draws the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want help, you might want to create a small working example which shows your problem, not just some code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pages = [(wx.Panel(parent = self.parent, id = wx.ID_ANY), name.capitalize()) for name in self.package.vars["tabs"]]
```

maybe this `wx.Panel` in the list comprehension still has the default color. what happens if you apply `SetBackgroundColour` to these panels as well?

(edit)

How about removing that boarder space by

`self.SetInternalBorder(0)`

self here is Toolbook class. It seems to work on wxPython Demo Toolbook example.

Comment: Tried that because it looked like a rolled up panel -- no dice, that blank spot seems to be a built in separator unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Perfect, your edit was the answer.  Didn't realize there was an internal border.